# Simple Mac To-Do list

Tags: osx, time-management

I love lists. I made list for everything, since shopping to what todo today ... Even lists of options for movies or food.

But one of the most usabilities for lists for me is, ToDo lists for tasks to work on.

e.g.

- Talk to the client.
- Create an specification for this.
- Clone the button from screen X to screen Y, changing his color.

and so on...

In the OSX there is an app called `Notes`

[image: Notes]

This app has a friendly layout, easy to deal with and has an historic for all my notes (at the left side). But I couldn't create an efficiently ToDo list on it.

I googled about and found a little bit more than I wished for... So I'm looking for a recommendation since Mac OS X is blessed (or perhaps plagued) with more to-do apps than you could ever use.

I saw list like

- [Wunderlist](https://www.wunderlist.com/en/) (that looks like it has mobile support, and a great UI for OSX)
- [Simple Task](http://www.adamfishercox.com/demos/simpletaskapp/mac.html)
- [Anxiety](http://www.anxietyapp.com/)
- [TaskMate](http://gettaskmate.com/)
- [EtreTask](http://www.etresoft.com/etretask.html)

and tons of others...

I'm looking for (**Needed**):

- Works on Mac OSX.
- Possible way to see all lists that I have.
- Easy to work with (Clean and objective UI).
- Add notes or small sumaries about the ToDo List (Sometimes I forget what exactly is the list with just his title) .
- Cloud storage.
- Be Able to work offline

But I would be pleased if (**Optional**):

- Would be gratis.
- Also work with Android.
- Possible to add notes to itens on the checklist (Instead of keep open parentheses, and others "tags" to increment the description of the item. would be nice to be able to add a small note about it. and let the item be more direct on the point).
- Possible create folders to store Lists. e.g.:

  - Folder: Work

    1. Item1
    2. Item2
  - Folder: Personal

    1. ItemX
    2. ItemY

Comment: It doesn't really meet the criteria but I like [TaskPaper](http://www.hogbaysoftware.com/products/taskpaper) and in combination with Dropbox it kinda has cloud storage :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use and love [**Wunderlist**](https://www.wunderlist.com/en/). Let's see how far high on your list it's at:

> Works on Mac OSX.

**Yup**. I'm a Mac user and Wunderlist is perfect. Sometimes, it can feel a little heavy, but mostly no issues.

> Possible way to see all lists that I have.

**Yes**. There's a sidebar with all your lists, and lists that Wunderlist makes for you. For example, a list called "Week" pops up when something is due this week, and hides when there's not.

> Easy to work with (Clean and objective UI).

**Yes**. It's very to-the-point app with no ads and no frills.

> Add notes or small sumaries about the ToDo List (Sometimes I forget what exactly is the list with just his title) .

**No**. I have never really felt like I needed this. Maybe you should try giving more descriptive names to lists?

> Cloud storage.

**Yes**. Not sure what you mean here. But Wunderlist has cloud sync, and you can attach files to an item as well.

> Be Able to work offline

**Yes**. But obviously, sync won't work.

> Would be gratis.

**Yes**. I'm a free user.

> Also work with Android.

**Yes**. I'm an Android user. The experience is very desktop-like.

> Possible to add notes to itens on the checklist (Instead of keep open parentheses, and others "tags" to increment the description of the item. would be nice to be able to add a small note about it. and let the item be more direct on the point).

**Yes**. I love this about Wunderlist. Other than notes, you can add a checklist in an item too.

> Possible create folders to store Lists.

**No**. Lists are lists. I think if you need folders to manage lists, you're doing to-do wrong.

---

I would say Wunderlist is amazing, and a perfect option for you given your need!

Comment: Op linked to it, but done! :)

Comment: Until now, it's my favorite. =)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [TaskAgent](http://macrecon.com/taskagent/index.html)?

It uses plain-text syntax to create lists, therefore, even if there's no Android app, you can still open your lists with any plain text editor. Content is synced via Dropbox. You get a nice sidebar with all your lists, can add notes to your tasks and folders of lists. Not free, but cheap: you can get the Mac version for $5.99 right now.